# Pasar de php a javascript y obtener información de otra pagina

Tags: php, curl

Hola me gustaría ayuda a sacar información de una pagina externa usando javasript . encontré este código php.

```
<?php  
$id=$_GET['id'];
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.m.com/videos/?v='.$id); 
// mp4 
$sd = explode('[{file', $url); 
$sd = explode('",label:', $sd[1]); 
$sd = explode(': "', $sd[0]); 
 // jpg 
$img = explode('[{image', $url); 
$img = explode('",sources:', $img[1]); 
$img = explode(': "', $img[0]); 
?>
```

Esta es una mejor forma de lograrlo

```
<?php  
$id = $_GET['id'];
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.mooplayer.com/xvideos/?v='.$id); 
// mp4 
if (preg_match('#\[{file:[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $url, $datos)) {
    $sd = $datos[1];
} else {
    $sd = 'error';
}
if (preg_match('#\[{image:[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $url, $datos)) {
    $img = $datos[1];
} else {
    $img = 'error';
}
?><p>$sd: <?= htmlspecialchars($sd) ?></p>
<p>$img: <?= htmlspecialchars($img) ?></p>
```

Lastimosamente los dos dan el mismo error :

```
file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

Es posible adaptar este método a mi propósito?

```
$url = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/apps/index.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Para lograr extraer la información

Comment: Ese código es difícil de mantener, las expresiones regulares te harán la vida más sencilla (redactando).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mejoras en PHP

Las expresiones regulares te podrán ayudar a hacer más fácil tu trabajo en PHP:

```
<?php  
$id = $_GET['id'];
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.mooplayer.com/xvideos/?v='.$id); 
// mp4 
if (preg_match('#\[{file:[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $url, $datos)) {
    $sd = $datos[1];
} else {
    $sd = 'error';
}
if (preg_match('#\[{image:[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $url, $datos)) {
    $img = $datos[1];
} else {
    $img = 'error';
}
?><p>$sd: <?= htmlspecialchars($sd) ?></p>
<p>$img: <?= htmlspecialchars($img) ?></p>
```

## Código en javascript

Por desgracia no podrás realizar el mismo trabajo en javascript porque la protección de [CRSF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) del navegador te lo impedirá con un mensaje del estilo:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.mooplayer.com/xvideos/?v=(id). No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://mi-servidor-de-pruebas.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

Comment: hola gracias por la información funciona bien solo tengo una pregunta la url del  vídeo esta en esta forma. {html5player. setVideoUrlHigh(' video.mp4 ');} como puedo sacarla usando expresiones regulares

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que el paréntesis `(` es un carácter especial en las expresiones regulares (sirve para agrupar los patrones) deberías escaparlo con una contrabarra `\(` para que funcione. Quedaría: [`#setVideoUrlHigh\('([^']*)'#`](https://regex101.com/r/IXzjI1/1).

Comment: gracias por la respuesta

Comment: De nada, agrégate a favoritos la página que te he proporcionado, te será muy útil para desarrollar expresiones regulares, comprobar si funcionan, ver la explicación de los grupos de captura (en la derecha) y probarlas al vuelo: https://regex101.com/r/IXzjI1/1

Comment: Agregada a favoritos y a estudiar para aprender gracias por el dato saludes

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia resulta que el codigo php da el siguiente error:
**file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused**
y no logro a serlo funcionar.
e escuchado que es posible usando este método .
**$url = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/apps/index.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);**

pero no se como adaptarlo al propósito que busco para extraer la información espero tu ayuda si es posible gracias

Comment: Sí, se puede usar curl también, pero si te pone conexión rechazada es probable que tu proveedor de alojamiento no permita conexiones hacia el exterior o bien que la página que intentas acceder te haya bloqueado.

Comment: es algo estaño e provado con diferentes paginas y hostin y da igual  en file_get_contents  pero en  curl_ini aun no se mucho del tema

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo a traves de un ajax, trabajando con el resultado devuelto por la petición, puedes hacerlo de dos formas: 1 - la que te dejo aqui por cierto no la he probado y pudiera ser mejor si dejaras el ejemplo del valor devuelto por file_get_contents, y la segunda manteniendo tu código php de arriba y accediendo a el desde php para que vayas obteniendo la información que deseas cambiando solo el id.

Aquí esta la primera opción, Imaginate que tienes un campo de texto llamado "a" donde pones el id del video del cual quieres saber sus datos, y tienes un botón "Enviar" donde haces click para que realice esa acción. Usando jquery entonces queda de esta forma:

```
$('#enviar').on('click', function(){
    //Obtengo el id del video que quiero conocer sus datos
    var id = $('#movie_id').val();

    //Ejecuto el ajax para realizar la operación
    $.ajax({
      //Url a la cual consultar
      'url': 'https://www.mooplayer.com/xvideos/',
      'method': 'GET',
      //id del video que será pasado a la url
      'data': {'v': id},
      'dataType': 'text',
      //Cuando ocurra todo perfectamente se ejecutará lo siguiente
      'success': function(json){
          //Esto es el homólogo de tu código en php (Si me das el resultado de file_get_contents a esa url podría mejorarlo)
          // mp4 
          var sd = json.split('[{file'); 
          sd = sd[1].split('",label:'); 
          sd = sd[0].split(': "'); 
          // jpg 
          var img = json.split('[{image'); 
          img = img[1].split('",sources:'); 
          img = img[0].split(': "'); 
      },
      'error': function(){
         alert("Ha ocurrido un error.");
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah por cierto se puede hacer con la función $.get de jquery que es más sencilla. No he probado el ejemplo de arriba. Luego me dices. Saludos

Comment: No funciona porque las protecciones de CSRF te lo impedirán.